# SQL Function not working the way I want

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I wrote these 2 functions:

```
USE muziekdatabase
GO
CREATE FUNCTION fnSpecNivAantal
    (
        @Niveau as char(1)
    )

RETURNS char(1)
AS 

BEGIN

    DECLARE @Aantal AS int

    IF @Niveau = 'A'
    SET @Aantal = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUK WHERE niveaucode = 'A')

    ELSE IF @Niveau = 'B' 
    SET @Aantal = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUK WHERE niveaucode = 'B')

    ELSE IF @Niveau = 'C'
    SET @Aantal = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUK WHERE niveaucode = 'C')

RETURN @Aantal

END

USE muziekdatabase
GO

ALTER FUNCTION fnHoogsteNummer 
    (
        @EersteNummer as numeric,
        @TweedeNummer as numeric
    )
RETURNS numeric 
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @HoogsteNummer as VARCHAR(MAX)

    IF MAX(@Eerstenummer) > MAX(@TweedeNummer)
    SET @HoogsteNummer = @EersteNummer
    ELSE IF
    MAX(@Tweedenummer) > MAX(@Eerstenummer)
    SET @HoogsteNummer = @TweedeNummer
    ELSE IF
    @EersteNummer = @TweedeNummer
    SET @HoogsteNummer = 'Nummers zijn gelijk' 
    ELSE
    SET @HoogsteNummer = 'Er is iets fout gegaan'

    RETURN @HoogsteNummer
END
```

Now they pretty much work like they should. But there's one thing that's not quite right. When I insert a value into my function, the outcome is a whole list with the same answer. Like 10 rows with just a 3, where it only should be 1 row with the number 3. I know I can use `DISTINCT`, but I think something is wrong with the function. I tried to use `CASE / WHEN` but that's not working either..

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code is product specific.)

Comment: MS SQL Server 2017

Comment: @MrEmper . . . Your code has so many errors, that I'm voting to close as too broad.  (Using `MAX()` with no `SELECT`, setting strings equal to a number, return a string when the function is defined as returning a number, and no doubt more).

Comment: It runs without any error, could you please keep to the point?

Comment: It is to the point, there are so many errors in the query any one could help in not doing what you expect. Fix these first

Comment: How can I fix it if it doesn't give any errors or I do not know what's wrong with it? I just had a simple question, not to revamp the whole thing..

Comment: You said the function does not do what you expected. That is not because there are syntax errors, but logical errors. Some might be not obviouse but for example using MAX() without a select is a logical error. It returns no exception, but does not do what you think it should. There are more problems like this one in your query

Comment: It does what it should do, only the way it presents the data is not the way I want it. I only asked for that piece to get me going.

Comment: can you include the query that uses these functions and some input sample and the desired output?

Comment: I would take a look at converting these scalar functions to inline table valued functions instead. There is a huge performance boost with a slightly different approach to functions.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange, you actually helped me with my next exercise haha, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnSpecNivAantal
(
 @Niveau as char(1)
)
RETURNS INT  --<-- since you are returning count use INT variable not char
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Aantal AS int; 

    IF (@Niveau IN ('A' , 'B', 'C'))
     BEGIN
       SELECT @Aantal = COUNT(*) 
       FROM STUK WHERE niveaucode = @Niveau
     END

RETURN @Aantal

END
```

And sorry cannot make any sense of your second function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Even though it looks a lot better, it still gives the same result. https://i.imgur.com/XKMtrgI.png

Comment: The function is executed for each row in your table. If you want a simple count you shouldn't use a function, and definitely not with `SELECT *`.

Comment: My hero, this is the solution! Thanks all for the feedback and working towards the right answer, I learned a lot, also the way I need to use this forum!

Answer (score 0):

Changing these function to inline table valued functions will offer some performance benefits. They are a little different way to think about functions but well worth the effort. One habit you need to get into is defining the size and precision of your variables and parameters. Do NOT get lazy and do things like numeric. You should be precise and define the size. SQL Server does not automatically adjust the scale and precision to meet the values it finds. On the contrary it uses a default size which may or may not fit with your data.

Your first function can be great simplified to this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnSpecNivAantal
(
    @Niveau as char(1)
)RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

    SELECT Niveau = COUNT(*) 
    FROM STUK 
    WHERE niveaucode = @Niveau
        AND niveaucode IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

The second one is a little different. You defined your function as returning a numeric (no scale or precision) but your code can return a numeric or a string literal. This doesn't work because all parts of a function MUST return the same datatype. Not a huge deal you just have to realize that your return datatype is a varchar here and not a number. This function could be converted to an inline table valued function like this.

```
ALTER FUNCTION fnHoogsteNummer 
    (
        @EersteNummer as numeric, --need to define scale and precision
        @TweedeNummer as numeric --need to define scale and precision
    )
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

    SELECT CASE WHEN @Eerstenummer > @TweedeNummer THEN convert(varchar(25), @EersteNummer)
            WHEN @TweedeNummer > @EersteNummer THEN convert(varchar(25), @TweedeNummer)
            WHEN @TweedeNummer = @EersteNummer THEN 'Nummers zijn gelijk' 
            ELSE 'Er is iets fout gegaan'
            END
```

Please note that both of these functions are a single statement. This is what makes them an inline table valued function. If you start defining variables and have multiple statements it becomes a multi-statement table valued function and the performance can be even worse than a scalar function.